# MongoDB replication on a single server

Tags: replication, mongodb

I am working on a project with a Mongo Database for storage.
The current setup is one Virtual Machine with a single Mongo Database.
We notice a performance degradation when executing some heavy queries.

Would it help to create a replication set on the same Virtual Machine and run the queries on the secondary member (readPreference=secondary)? I know that the best practice would be to put each member on a different machine, but for our client this not an option.

Comment: Adding more contention for resources in the same VM is likely to make performance significantly worse, not better. I would start by looking into optimising the "heavy queries" to perform better. My comments and answer on [MongoDB standalone performs better than replica set](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204602/9345) addresses a similar question.